# How to allocated a fixed resources to vertices of graph yet low degree vertices get more?

Tags: math, graph

I have a simple problem to solve, but I'm stuck and I need your help. The problem is as follows:

I have three nodes `A,B,C` with degree `11, 6, 1` and I have 20 resources to allocate to each node based on their degree. I know when I want the large  degree nodes to get more resources the formula is:

```
just sum all degrees (11+6+1)=18 and distribute the resources as follows:
A=(20/18)*11 and similar for the other nodes
```

What if I want the low degree node to get more resources than the large one? I mean `Node C` of degree 1 to get more resources than nodes A and B.

I tried this:

```
A = (20/18)* (11)^r
```

Such that when `r=1`, larger degree will have more resources. But the reverse is not true, for example when `r=-1`, the total resources won't sum to 20. What to do?

Is there a way in which for the same formula, I can plug in different values of `r` and give results for both low and large degree?

Your help will be much appreciated, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

When there are at least 2 nodes, is this a possibility with either `r=0` for more resources to the highest degrees or `r=1` for more resources to the lowest degrees:

```
(degree_sum*r - nodes[n]) * resources / ((num_nodes*r - 1) * degree_sum)
```

Simplied, for `r=1`, the formula would be to give every node in proportion to "the sum of all degrees minus the degree of the current node" (with `nodes[n]` the degree of the current node):

```
(degree_sum - nodes[n]) * resources / ((num_nodes - 1) * degree_sum)
So, this would give:
A: (18 - 11) * 20 / (2 * 18)
B: (18 -  6) * 20 / (2 * 18)
C: (18 -  1) * 20 / (2 * 18)
```

Here is a demo program in Python to demonstrate the idea:

```py
nodes = {'A': 11, 'B': 6, 'C': 1}
resources = 20

degree_sum = sum(nodes[n] for n in nodes)
num_nodes = len(nodes)
print("sum of all degrees:", degree_sum, "- number of nodes", num_nodes)

distribution_highest_more = {n: nodes[n] * resources / degree_sum for n in nodes}
print("higher degrees get more:", distribution_highest_more)
print("  total:", sum(distribution_highest_more[n] for n in distribution_highest_more))

distribution_lowest_more = {n: (degree_sum - nodes[n]) * resources / ((num_nodes - 1) * degree_sum) for n in nodes}
print("lower degrees get more:", distribution_lowest_more)
print("  total:", sum(distribution_lowest_more[n] for n in distribution_lowest_more))

for r in range(2):
    distribution = {n: (degree_sum*r - nodes[n]) * resources / ((num_nodes*r - 1) * degree_sum) for n in nodes}
    print("distribution for r =", r, ":")
    print("  ", distribution)
    print("  total:", sum(distribution[n] for n in distribution))
```

Which prints:

```
sum of all degrees: 18 - number of nodes 3
higher degrees get more: {'A': 12.222222222222221, 'B': 6.666666666666667, 'C': 1.1111111111111112}
  total: 20.0
lower degrees get more: {'A': 3.888888888888889, 'B': 6.666666666666667, 'C': 9.444444444444445}
  total: 20.0
distribution for r = 0 :
   {'A': 12.222222222222221, 'B': 6.666666666666667, 'C': 1.1111111111111112}
  total: 20.0
distribution for r = 1 :
   {'A': 3.888888888888889, 'B': 6.666666666666667, 'C': 9.444444444444445}
  total: 20.0
```